# Tridion Dynamic Link not resolving in Dynamic Component Presentation

Tags: content-delivery, 2013, dynamic-linking

I'm implementing functionality in SDL Tridion 2013 where the user is able to utilise a filter which in turn queries the broker for matching criteria and then returns the Component Presentations to the page. Each item returned contains a Dynamic link.

(the dynamic CPs were stored in the broker DB as HTML fragments by publishing.)

When I publish DCP and access the page used DCP, HTML tag which is used Tridion Tag is disappear.(refer to output HTML.)

To solve the above problem, I refer to the follow site. But i can't solove.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532565/tridion-component-link-not-resolving-in-dynamic-component-presentation

So, Please tell me how to solve the above problem.

The Java code is below.

```
package com.tridion.tag.news;

import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import com.tridion.broker.querying.*;
import com.tridion.broker.querying.criteria.*;
import com.tridion.broker.querying.criteria.metadata.*;
import com.tridion.dynamiccontent.ComponentPresentationAssembler;

public class NewsSearch implements Tag {
    private PageContext pageContext;
    private Tag parentTag;
    private String criteria;
    private ComponentPresentationAssembler cpAssembler;
    private String componentId;
    private String componentTemplateURI = "tcm:19-1149-32";

    @Override
    public void setPageContext(PageContext pageContext) {
        this.pageContext = pageContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Tag getParent() {
        return this.parentTag;
    }

    @Override
    public void setParent(Tag parentTag) {
        this.parentTag = parentTag;
    }

    public void setCriteria(String criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria ;
    }

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        try {
            JspWriter writer=pageContext.getOut();
            // create criteria
            CustomMetaKeyCriteria keyCriteria = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("date");
            CustomMetaValueCriteria modelCriteria = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(keyCriteria, criteria, "yyyy",Criteria.NOT_EQUAL);
            // create query
            Query query = new Query(modelCriteria);
            // execute query
            String[] queryResult = query.executeQuery();
            if (queryResult != null) {
                int count = queryResult.length;
                cpAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler(22);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    componentId = queryResult[i];
                    writer.print(cpAssembler.getContent(componentId, componentTemplateURI));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JspException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }

    @Override
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void release() {

    }
}
```

The DWT code (PT) is below.(For the debug, the criteria is fixed value(2014).)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="cd_tags" prefix="tridion" %>
<%@ taglib uri="cd_tags" prefix="news" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ja" xml:lang="ja">
  <head>test</head>
  <body> 
    <news:NewsSearch criteria="2014" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The DWT code (CT) is below.

```
<tr>
  <th><img src="@@newsImage@@" alt="@@newsImageAlt@@" width="70" height="14" /></th>
    <td class="date">@@date@@</td>
     <td><ul>
       <li><a tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@">@@RenderComponentField("Fields.title",0)@@</a></li>
     </ul></td>
</tr>
```

The output HTML is below.

```
<span><!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:22-1226", "ComponentModified" : "2014-03-24T10:35:48", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:22-1149-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2014-03-19T13:21:02", "IsRepositoryPublished" : true } -->

<tr>
  <th><img src="/ms/Images/press_icon.gif"  alt="press" width="70" height="14" /></th>
    <td class="date">2014年03月04日</td>
      <td><ul>
         <li></li>
      </ul></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most likely your Dynamic Component Template output type is set to `HTML Fragment`.  This instructs Tridion to not do anything with the rendered output as it is plain static HTML.

Change your template output type to `REL` when storing DCPs in the database, or `JSP Scripting` if storing them on the filesystem.

[image]

Comment: >Dear Nickoli Roussakov.   thank you to answer my question. I can solve the above problem by your solution. Thank you to help me.

Comment: And the picture helps!