# Content not showing in published Pages

Tags: content-delivery, publishing

I have an issue with content within a Component Presentation not being displayed on a published page.

I can see the content when I Preview the Component Presentation, and when I Preview the Page, within the Tridion CME. Also, I see the content of the Component Presentation when running this through Template Builder. However, the content within the Component Presentation is not shown on the published page.

The Page is getting published successfully. It shows the HTML from within the Page Template's Dreamweaver Template (DWT) - The only thing missing is the content of the Component Presentation, which I assume means that this is not getting rendered on the published page somehow.

The Page is static, it's not using any Dynamic Component Presentations.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You'll need to provide some more information here as to how you're publishing the content / storing it &c.

Comment: We are publishing the content from CMS to CDA and both are on different AWS servers. We have used Default finish actions. ARe we missing anything over here or let me know what else information should I provide you?

Comment: i'm sorry but that's not very detailed, i think you've a lot of gaps missing in your SDL knowledge here, it might be worth you looking at the documentation (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql) to read the chapters on publishing and content delivery

Comment: How are the components added to the page? Are these dynamic Component Presentations? Where are they stored? Which type of DCPs? Try making them "Embedded CPs" first.

Comment: John, let me give you some more information. I have published a page, the page is getting published, and its having the DWT HTML code part. Only thing missing is the content of the component which means the component is not getting rendered on the page.

Comment: Its just the static CPs only.

Comment: What's in the source of the page in the File System? Is the component presentation there?

Comment: I am responding on the behalf of user "user918"

Comment: Actually our page is static , its not using any dynamic presentation , while viewing the preview of the page and that CP then data of the component is displaying in preview , but after doing publishing its not showing those value of component in the page.

Comment: I've tried improving the question with the information given in the comments (it helps to add that information to the actual question rather than just leaving it in a comment), but there still is hardly any information for people to respond to. Keep in mind that we cannot see or access your system, so you need to provide all relevant information about what you exactly did and what you see. Otherwise all you can expect is a guess at what might be wrong which is not a proper format of a question.

Answer (score 3):

This type of behavior typically occurs when your Component Template is set to dynamic, but your Content Delivery environment and/or Pages are not setup correctly.

For instance, your pages could be using the .html extension, which (by default) will not execute server-side code. Since DCPs get added to the pages on the server-side, the content will not be loaded if your extension is .html. A clear sign that this is happening is that you'll see tags like this:

```
<tridion:ComponentPresentation [...] />
```

in your page source in the browser.

Another possible reason is that your Publication Target is configured to use "Language: None", which means that Tridion can't create the required Content Delivery API calls to load your Dynamic Component Presentations.

Yet another possible reason is that you configured your Component Templates to use output format "Jsp" or "Ascx" but didn't configure it properly in your cd_storage_conf.xml on the delivery side.

And the list goes on and on. Adding more detail (for instance, covering the examples I mentioned above) will help us help you.

**UPDATE**

Just want to mention one of the comments added to this thread by Alvin: Can you make sure your Page and Component Templates are correctly *checked in* in Tridion? Preview and Template Builder will use the latest version of those templates, but the publisher will only use checked in versions.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, will check all these key points mentioned by you and will let you know in case these might not be the case.

Comment: Check this answer if this is what Nuno mentioned above: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4986/tridion-dynamic-link-not-resolving-in-dynamic-component-presentation

Comment: we don't have any dynamic cps. we hv only embedded cps.

Comment: Weird then. Can you verify they are in the page content (the published file)?

Comment: @Nuno: Could this be because of some TBBs are missing as right now we are using "Default finish action TBB" only, or because of some configuration of storage config file

Comment: Not with embedded CPs. If you see it in preview you should see it when published. Is there workflow involved?

Comment: <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="fileStorage" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
    <Root Path="c:\tridion\tork"/>
   </Storage>
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="fileStorage" cached="false">  
 <publication Id="16" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="true">
   <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="fileStorage"/>
   <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="fileStorage"/>
        </publication>
    </ItemTypes>

Comment: above is the storage config file's entries.

Comment: No Nuno, there is no workflow involves

Comment: What about what is actually in the published page? Do you see the Component content if you open the file with Notepad or something like that?

Comment: Yes, i saw by opening the published page in notepad, except the data of the component every thing is there on the page like Html,JS reference means every thing

Comment: And it doesn't show in the browser? Then it has nothing to do with Tridion but with your HTML/JS/CSS. You may want to add the source of the page to the original question so we can take a look.

Comment: then why its showing in the preview of the page, below is the DWT code where we are calling the text field of the component.
The same field is displaying in preview but not in published page

Comment: <div style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="font-family:'HelveticaNeue', arial, sans-serif; font-size:24px; text-decoration:none;">
                                          <img src="img/push-area1.png" width="130" height="149" alt=""><br><span style="color:#39acdd; font-weight:bold;">@@text@@</span></a>
                        </div>

Comment: The biggest gotcha I've seen when the Template is "perfect" but nothing is published is not checking in the Template. Around Tridion 2009/2011 you could simply save (without closing) to see a nice preview without ever publishing the right rendered content. Save and close the template to be sure. Otherwise confirm the component itself is checked in and you're previewing the right content. Also you *can* embed a CP dynamically as well as statically.

Comment: @Nash don't respond to a comment by adding code, that is not readable and not useful. Edit the question if you have more information to add. In a question you can also properly format any code added which makes it readable. I suggest you delete your comments with code here and add all that information in the question.

Answer (score 2):

As you answer, you did not do any custom templating code and just use the `Default Finish Action` TBB.

Assuming:

1.you are using Tridion supplied “Default Finish Action TBB” on the page.

2.In CT you have written proper code to render the content of the Component.

Now, I don’t think the “Default Finish Action TBB” will render any content for you.
Check the details about this TBB [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-EF142CAA-A9EB-4B8C-862F-7D70135ED879&addHistory=true&query=default%2520finish%2520actions&scope=&tid=e59be990-f978-4f34-966a-85f038de2e60&filename=GUID-EF142CAA-A9EB-4B8C-862F-7D70135ED879.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EF142CAA-A9EB-4B8C-862F-7D70135ED879&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=default%2520finish%2520actions&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1396550525530&currentQuery=default%2520finish%2520actions&currentScope=) (Login Required)

So you need to add a TBB to the Page Template, which renders the component presentations on the page.

Of course you can do the component presentation preview on the page as PT has no role in it and only CT is used to display the output (though, I am still surprised you are getting the preview for the page)

Please add a TBB (to render ComponentPrasentations) on the Page Template like a DWT TBB having code like below:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

I hope, this helps.

Comment: we are not using any templating except the default finish action TBB's, and preview is working fine for both CP and page.

Comment: Can you confirm that the expected content is not present in the published file?

Comment: yes its not present in the published file as i confirmed by opening that file in notepad.

Comment: On the other comment thread you said the content WAS present in the published file... I suggest you move this discussion to the chat channel and we stop polluting this question